# Using image paths from database to display images in php

Tags: php

I have a database called imageloc with a table ogloc. In this table there is an id row and a location row. The location row has the filepath to several images I would like to display on a website. I tried to assign mysqli_fetch_array($result) to a variable, in the hopes that I can just use this variable in the  and reiterate displaying of images, until all images have been displayed. This however did not work out and I kept getting errors that I cannot assign $result to another variable. Much thanks for any feedback.

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imageloc");  

 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>image file location displaying</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Insert and Display Images</h3>   
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
                     <tr>  
                          <th>Image</th>  
                     </tr>  
                <?php  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM ogloc ORDER BY id DESC";  
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                     echo '  
                          <tr>  
                               <td>  

                                     <img src="$result" height="50%" width="100%" class="img-thumnail" />  

                               </td>  
                          </tr>  
                     ';  


                }  
                ?>  
                </table>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you'd like to do correctly, the variable you should use for the image source is not $result, but rather $row, and depending on your data-structure, probably something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {  
    echo '<tr>  
            <td>  
                <img src="' . $row["location"] . '" height="50%" width="100%" class="img-thumnail" />
            </td>  
        </tr>';  
}
```